# Bootstrap 4 dropdown not working: Uncaught TypeError?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I cannot get my bootstrap 4 dropdown menu to work. I know this has been asked before but I have tried everything on all of the other threads. I'm getting an 'uncaught TypeError: cannot read property 'fn' of undefined' at bootstrap.min.js and at util.js when I look at the console. I'm not sure if this is the problem or how to resolve these errors.

Here is my header code:

```
<head>
<title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/layout.css' %}">

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat|PT+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro" rel="stylesheet"> 
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/open-iconic/1.1.1/font/css/open-iconic-bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha256-BJ/G+e+y7bQdrYkS2RBTyNfBHpA9IuGaPmf9htub5MQ=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel='shortcut icon' type='image/x-icon' href='/static/css/favicon.ico' />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

 </head>
```

Here is the code for the navbar including the dropdown menu:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-white">
    <a class="navbar-left logo" href="{% url 'home' %}"><img class="logo" src="/static/css/brand.jpg"></a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <div class="navbar-nav">

            <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" action="{% url 'search:search_users' %}" method="GET" value="{{request.GET.q}}">
              <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" name="q" value="{{request.GET.q}}" placeholder="Search by Skill">
              <button class="btn btn-primary my-2 my-sm-0" id = "search" name="submit" type="submit" value ="Search">Search</button>
            </form>

            <div class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Find Expertise</a>

              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'browse' %}">Browse Researchers</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'booking:request_expert' %}">Request Expertise</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'booking:tutorial_list' %}">Find a Tutorial</a>
              </div>
            </div>


            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'booking:tutorial_list' %}">TUTORIALS</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'faq' %}">FAQ</a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'profile' %}">MY PROFILE</a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'booking:booking_list' %}"> MY SCHEDULE</a>
              <a class ="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'logout' %}">LOGOUT</a>

        </div>
      </div>
</nav>
```

I also tried to change the order of the jquery, popper and bootstrap files. Further, I tried to replace these files with the latest versions however, the dropdown menu still does not work. All of the other javascript on the site is working fine.

Comment: `fn` is from jquery. U didn't load it probably.

Comment: How would I go about loading it? I was under the impression that putting it in the header should load it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you are using some package manager. If yes, try to install dependencies via it.
2. Import last versions of jQuery, popper and bootstrap.
3. Check. Maybe you are using another packages where you already imported jQuery. It should be imported just once.

Comment: Thanks for your response. What do you mean by using another package where I already imported jquery?

Comment: The problem comes from jQuery it doesn’t loads properly. Check if in your HTML file, maybe you imported it twice. And plese put <script>‘s tag at the end of <body> tag.

Comment: Thanks you helped me solve the problem! I was using a Django template tag at the top of the file that was causing jquery to load twice.